# Is there a way to see the amount of edited posts by user?

Tags: support, edits

As a user I'd like to find the amount of posts that I've edited.

Is it possible? Could it be a suggestion for improvement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the *number* of edits, go to the Users tab, click on the right-hand side on the "Editors" tab, select a time period, and editors are sorted by the number of edits they made in that period.

To see the total count of edits *you* made, select the "all" time period, and search for your name. Here's a screenshot of me searching for my own name:

[image]

In other words: [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) by time machine.

Answer (score 5):

It's in your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/970721/thecatontheflat?tab=activity&sort=revisions

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Shame on me that I was not so accurate :)